# Erro de consulta MySQL - Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,
Estou fazendo uma consulta com PHP e estou conectando ao banco de dados normal, porem ao retornar a consulta e montar na tabela está retornando o erro: **Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in** na linha 273 do meu código.

Na linha 273 eu possuo um While que eu estou buscando o array com os valores e salvando em uma variável para organizar na minha tabela depois. Segue a linha 273:

`while ($result =  mysqli_fetch_array($link, $query)) {`

Segue agora como está sendo feito a conexão:

`define("HOST","hostmysql");
    define("USER","usuario");
    define("PASSWORD","senha");
    define("DBNAME","nomeDB");
    $link = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD) or die("Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados");`

Aqui está a busca ao MySQL que estou fazendo junto com o While novamente:

```
`$query = "SELECT id, tipo, numero, ano, descricao, data, horario, arquivos, cadastro, status FROM lici ORDER BY id DESC";

while ($result =  mysqli_fetch_array($link, $query)) {`
```

Espero que isto ajude a me ajudar.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

A estrutura para consultas em mysql no php é a seguinte:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

/* numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);  

/* associative array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);  

/* associative and numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["CountryCode"]);  

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Antes do `mysqli_fetch_array`, execute o `mysqli_query` e passe o resultado para o `mysqli_fetch_array`.
Segundo manual: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

voce deve executar a Query... no seu caso o mysql_fetch_array está vindo vazio, pois nao foi executado a consulta.

lembre-se de fechar a conexão após a consulta.

exemplo:

```
$query= "SELECT id, tipo, numero, ano, descricao, data, horario, arquivos, cadastro, status FROM lici ORDER BY id DESC";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
if(mysqli_query($link, $query)){
    $result =  mysqli_fetch_array($link, $query);
    mysqli_close($link);
}else{
    die("Error:".$link->error);
    mysqli_close($link);
}
while ($result) {
    //restante do codigo
}
```